# How to Get Template column Total Throw javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik

How to get radgrid Template column total throw javascript codebehind.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the problem ... with one sentence i dont think anybody can read your mind :) ... please explain the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem her is the script

```
function ValueChanged(sender, args) {
        var grid = $find("<%=grd.ClientID %>");//grid id

        var totalAmount = 0;

        if (grid) {
            var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
            var Rows = MasterTable.get_dataItems();
            var footer = grid.get_masterTableViewFooter().get_element();
            //footer.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML = 'My Footer Text'; // Set the footer text 

            var TotalQnty = 0;
            var TotalNetAmount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {
                var row = Rows[i];
                var txtIND_QTY = row.findControl("txtgrdIndentQty");//gridcolumns
                var txtNetAmount =Number(row.findControl("txtgrdNetamount"));
                TotalQnty = TotalQnty + parseFloat(txtIND_QTY.get_value());
                TotalNetAmount = TotalNetAmount + txtNetAmount;
            }
            footer.rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML = "Rs. "+TotalQnty;
            footer.rows[0].cells[6].innerHTML = "Rs. "+TotalNetAmount;
            alert(TotalQnty);
            alert(TotalNetAmount);
        }
    }
```